# SQL Server The multi-part identifier issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my simple SQL but when I run it, then I am getting the error

> The multi-part identifier "bbajobs.jid" could not be bound.

Here is my sql

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY [bbajobs].JID
            ) AS RowNumber
        ,[BBAJobs].[JID]
        ,[AccountReference] AS [Acc Ref]
        ,[BBAJobs].[OEReference] AS [OERef]
        ,[JobType]
        ,[JobState]
        ,[JobShippedDate]
        ,[UPSShippingNumber]
        ,[CustomerName] [Customer Name]
        ,[ContactName] [Contact Name]
        ,[Telephone]
        ,[JobDescription]
        ,[CallRem].[rem]
        ,[CallRem].[callStatus]
        ,[CallRem].[ShopRemarks]
        ,CustomerNotes
        ,ShopNotes
        ,RecievedDate
        ,UserName
    FROM dbo.BBAJobs
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CallRem ON dbo.BBAJobs.JID = dbo.CallRem.jid
    ) x
WHERE 1 < 2
    AND bbajobs.jid IN (
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, data) AS [JID]
        FROM dbo.Split1('33180,33265,33047', ',')
        )
    AND RowNumber BETWEEN 1
        AND 20
```

The error is not very clear to me. so please guide me what to rectify. thanks

Comment: in place of AND bbajobs.jid use AND x.jid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a subquery named `x`, not `bbajobs`s.  You need to change the `where` clause:

```
WHERE 1 < 2
    AND x.jid IN (
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), data) AS [JID]
        FROM dbo.Split1('33180,33265,33047', ',')
        )
    AND RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 20;
```

I also added a length to the `varchar()` in the `convert()` function call.  *Never* use `varchar()` without a length.  This can introduce problems that are very difficult to debug.

Comment: i update my question because now another problem comes. please help

Comment: @Thomas If you have another problem, then you should post a new question.  Don't edit this post with new issues.  I rolled back your edit, please post a new question with those details.

Comment: yes i posted here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782716/sql-server-wrong-row-number-is-showing

Answer (score 1):

```
        ,UserName
    FROM dbo.BBAJobs
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CallRem ON dbo.BBAJobs.JID = dbo.CallRem.jid
    ) x
WHERE 1 < 2
    AND bbajobs.jid IN (       --<-- Now this is X.jid since it is coming from X
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, data) AS [JID]
        FROM dbo.Split1('33180,33265,33047', ',')
        )
    AND RowNumber BETWEEN 1
        AND 20
```

Correct way will be

```
        ,UserName
    FROM dbo.BBAJobs
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CallRem ON dbo.BBAJobs.JID = dbo.CallRem.jid
    ) x
WHERE 1 < 2
    AND x.jid IN (       --<-- Now this is X.jid since it is coming from X
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, data) AS [JID]
        FROM dbo.Split1('33180,33265,33047', ',')
        )
    AND RowNumber BETWEEN 1
        AND 20
```

Comment: i update my question because now another problem comes. please help